# How do I retrieve the system icon for a file in python or qt?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qfilesystemmodel

I have the path to a file/folder. How can I get the icon image in the system for this file/folder? I'm writing a customized file browse model for a `QTreeView` and would like to display the icon like what the `QFileSystemModel` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK QFileSystemModel relies on `QFileIconProvider` to get the correct icon.
You can do the same in your implementation by using the `icon (const QFileInfo  &info)` method.
This may work or not depending on the Desktop Environment you use.